# How do I use TornadoFX?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, tornadofx

Coming from Swift now want to get into Kotlin UI Apps so I am trying out TornadoFX in IntelliJ atm.

When creating an hbox in a View Class, invoking severeal elemants like buttons, textfields, etc., how can I change properties like their names, alignment or other?

Unfortunately tornadoFX/Kotlin is not as well documented as Swift.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would also try https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide  It is being updated more actively.

https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/4.%20Basic%20Controls.md should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted, this indeed the guide made by the creator

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, for everyone whos looking..:

https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/4.%20Basic%20Controls.md

Comment: please answer the question with your solution, rather than linking to an external site that could change or be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I thought I'd drop the link for what Edvin intends to be the definitive guide for TornadoFX:

https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/

The other answers are still valid but this is his intended official guide so this might last longer in case he eventually he deletes his github version.